# "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: PermanentRedirect. S3 Error Message: The bucket is in this region: us-east-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I try to follow this workshop https://gitflow-codetools.workshop.aws/en/, every thing well but when I try to create the lambda usinging cloudformation I got an error:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: 
  PermanentRedirect. S3 Error Message: The bucket is in this region: 
  us-east-1. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Lambda, 
  Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx, 
  Extended Request ID: null)" (RequestToken: xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

I'm using **eu-west-1** for this workshop, but I don't understand why the cloudformation create the bucket in **us-east-1**.

When I deploy the cloudformation in us-east-1 I don't get this error.

Any idea how should avoid this error ?

the template looks like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/IAMFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambda_FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodeCommitReadOnly
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCodePipelineFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchEventsFullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSCloudFormationFullAccess
  PipelineCreateLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'gitflow-workshop-create-pipeline'
      Description: 'Lambda Function to create pipelines on branch creation'
      Code:
        S3Bucket: 'aws-workshop-gitflow'
        S3Key: 'pipeline-create.zip'
      Handler: 'pipeline-create.lambda_handler'
      Runtime: 'python3.7'
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaRole
          - Arn
  PipelineCreateLambdaPermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    DependsOn: PipelineCreateLambdaFunction
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: "codecommit.amazonaws.com"
      FunctionName: 'gitflow-workshop-create-pipeline'
  PipelineDeleteLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'gitflow-workshop-delete-pipeline'
      Description: 'Lambda Function to delete pipelines on branch deletion'
      Code:
        S3Bucket: 'aws-workshop-gitflow'
        S3Key: 'pipeline-delete.zip'
      Handler: 'pipeline-delete.lambda_handler'
      Runtime: 'python3.7'
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaRole
          - Arn
  PipelineDeleteLambdaPermission:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Permission'
    DependsOn: PipelineDeleteLambdaFunction
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      Principal: "codecommit.amazonaws.com"
      FunctionName: 'gitflow-workshop-delete-pipeline'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First things first**, Lambda and S3 need to be in the same region.

**Secondly**, it looks like you're not the bucket owner (you haven't created the bucket yourself by looking at the template).

This means, the bucket you're using to retrieve the Lambda source code from is (I suppose coming from the workshop), and they decided to create that bucket in the region us-east-1. Enforcing you to also deploy your stack in the region us-east-1 (if you want to follow the workshop).

**But what if you really wanted to deploy this stack to eu-west-1?**

That would mean you need to create a bucket in region eu-west-1 with and copy the objects from the workshop bucket into your newly created bucket and update your CloudFormation template to point and retrive the Lambda source code from your newly created bucket (note you might need to name the bucket differently as bucket names are globally shared).

I hope this is a bit clear.

Comment: Exactly, I agree with you, the workshop should create a template with a custom bucket name where you can use for example bucket-name-region-account-id, like this we can avoid this issue. Thank you for the clear answer.

Comment: Good luck and have fun with the workshop! @Doesn'tMatter